# How to push a Netbeans project to Github as a subfolder (using Netbeans git)?

Tags: windows, git, github, netbeans

I participate in a student project. I want to contribute my (long existing) Netbeans project to the project, so I have to upload/push it to a Github repository (which belong to another participant).

I am new to Github and followed instructions:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/github_nb_screencast.html

The result was that all my code (~40 source files) were uploaded/pushed to the root/origin of the repository, which is of course annoying to other participants.

Now I need to figure out, how to move this code into a subdirectory, and make Netbeans to push changes into this directory henceworth.
So how do I set up a netbeans project to be a subfolder of the repository in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with NetBeans. I would suggest to:

1. Install git bash
2. Clone the github repository
3. Create or copy your project in that clone where you like
4. Open your project in NetBeans for adjustments